# Can Firebase handle logins over REST?

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase

The documentation claims:

"The Firebase JavaScript, Java, and Objective-C libraries provide built-in functionality for many login providers, but the REST API works a little differently. ... generate user login tokens with your own server side code."

There appears to be no library for .NET/Xamarin, so I need to use the REST API. But there is no "own server side code" on Firebase.

I'm interpreting this to mean I need a separate service (not Firebase) to host software to provide the registration and authentication endpoints. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

You could create binding projects and use the existing FirebaseUI iOS and Android libraries

### Xamarin Binding walk-throughs:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

### Firebase mobile libraries:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/

Otherwise, yes, you are correct, you would need to provide your own server side authorization system.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can! (answering the question in title title)

I just fiddlered (is that a word?) how the javascript SDK talks to firebase servers and it turns out it is quite straightforward.

At the beginning you let your user authenticate with your provider of choice (e.g. facebook). You grab the oauth access token and you POST that (don't forget the "application/json" header) to the following location:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=<YOUR API KEY>
```

The post data would like like this:

```
{ 
 "postBody":"access_token=<OAUTH ACCESS TOKEN>&providerId=<PROVIDER ID>",
 "requestUri":"http://localhost",
 "returnSecureToken":true
}
```

The `<PROVIDER ID>` can be one of the following

- facebook.com
- google.com
- twitter.com
- github.com

In return you get a nice json which contains a lot of information, one of which is the "idToken" which acts as the authentication token for making REST requests to firebase. You can set it as the "auth" URL parameter of your request.

I wrote a library to handle this (along with email+password & anonymous logins):

https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet

And I wrote a blog post about it:

http://blog.bezysoftware.net/firebase-authentication-csharp-library/

Answer (score 0):

The need for a server when using REST is not for the actual authentication (Although you will have to solve this issue too somehow), but for generating the tokens that can be used for the client to authenticate against the Firebase REST API.

From the documentation

> To authenticate a user with Custom Login, we must provide each client with a secure JWT that has been generated on a server. There are several helper libraries for generating JWTs given a Firebase app's secret. Our secret can be found under the Secrets tab in our Firebase app's dashboard.

Then you could attache this token to REST requests to be [authenticated](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-authenticating-requests):

```
'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/auth-example.json?auth=SERVER_GENERATED_TOKEN'
```